# Deleting a file in a queue in a Android service

Tags: android, android-service, android-service-binding

In my app I want to download and upload file from and to server. I am using service to do it. In `onStartCommand` I am creating a thread which will download the content. I showing a notification of the download which has a pending intent. While clicking the notification it will show `ProcessManager`  which has the ongoing process of upload and download.

My problem is I want to delete the files in upload or download queue from the `ProcessManager` page. 
I cant use intent service because I need to get the downloading status every time I launch. I used both `Service and BindService`. Please guide me the way to do this.

Comment: ProcessManager, BindService what are those guys?

Comment: Is the upload/download queue in your service? Do you have individual service instances for each file or only one service instance managing all files?